# I cannot export my mesh to OBJ, DAE or FBX

Tags: modeling, objects, export, import, error

I just finished a game-ready character model with a relativily low poly count. I was going to export the object into Mixamo auto-rig when I noticed that my model was missing after I exported the model.

I tested going back to blender to upload my OBJ and FBX versions of the model into a new blender setup, when I did that nothing appeared again.

I checked my export settings and everything seemed to be right (selection only activated, applying different modifiers before export, etc). I also tried to export my model with DAE and my first error message appeared saying "no meshes have been selected".

Its weird because I HAVE selected it and troubleshooted most things, but I have still not found the solution. It seems as if the mesh itself doesn't exist?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots showing what is in your scene/selected/your export settings? Are there any other useful error messages anywhere? A sample blernd file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ could also be useful in finding the problem

Comment: There are no error messages, the only hint I get that I can tell is wrong is that the loading time of exporting the object is instant, as if I exported nothing. https://i.gyazo.com/c7667e12682130baaaf11b6814549737.png https://i.gyazo.com/fb5775001c56e3c485b99b540ed5771e.png https://i.gyazo.com/e1972a873e4dfc7ab8cb8dca4769876a.png https://i.gyazo.com/f2aa94db405280ebf0307729c2a67fd4.png

Comment: Also, for some reason I cannot share this blender file, "blend-exchange" tells me there is an error uploading it. :S

Comment: Another note: Tried exporting to Substance painter and it said that there are no meshes in the scene. https://gyazo.com/206acd5dc1ee8ac43f71f07f4676eda2